# Matrix averages in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix

I have a matrix, lets use this one for example:

```
[ [4.0, 2.0, 0.6],
  [4.2, 2.1, 0.59], 
  [3.9, 2.0, 0.58], 
  [4.3, 2.1, 0.62], 
  [4.1, 2.2, 0.63] ]
```

Now, I take the average of each column, which results in this:

```
 [4.10, 2.08, 0.604]
```

All these I'm able to make, I have the informations.

What I'm having problem is at this part now. I'm looking a way to subtract each average element with his respective element on the first Matrix.

It should look like this:

```
[ [-0.1, -0.08, -0.004],
  [0.1, 0.02, -0.014],
  [-0.2, -0.08, -0.024],
  [0.2, 0.02, 0.016],
  [0.0, 0.12, 0.026]  ]
```

I have to make it viable for an arbitrary-sized matrix.

Comment: You may like to write a helper function that takes the "media" and a single row of the input matrix and produces a single row of the output matrix. I encourage you to give this a try and include your thoughts on this in the question!

Comment: Well, the biggest problem here is that I have to make it work with a Amxn matrix, a "infinite" one. That is why I'm stuck.

Comment: Infinite in which dimension?  If rows, how do you compute the mean?

Comment: I think you'll find it easier to work with rows of a transposed matrix than with columns of the original matrix.

Answer (score 2):

something like this, without validations and formatting

```
colmean rs = let (a,c) = agg rs in map (/(fromIntegral c)) a

agg [r] = (r,1)
agg (r:rs) = let (a,c) = agg rs in (zipWith (+) a r, c+1)

minus = flip (zipWith (-))

demean x = map (minus $ colmean x) x

> demean media
[[-9.999999999999964e-2,-8.000000000000007e-2,-4.0000000000000036e-3],
 [0.10000000000000053,2.0000000000000018e-2,-1.4000000000000012e-2],
 [-0.19999999999999973,-8.000000000000007e-2,-2.400000000000002e-2],
 [0.20000000000000018,2.0000000000000018e-2,1.6000000000000014e-2],
 [0.0,0.1200000000000001,2.6000000000000023e-2]]
```

with this, the second dimension (number of columns) can be infinite

```
> map (take 10) $ demean [[1..], [2..]]
[[-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5],
 [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]]
```

Comment: Good answer! Two suggestions: `minus = zipWith (--)` and `agg` may be written in terms of `foldr`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
mean l = sum l / (fromIntegral (length l))

getColumnMeans = map mean . transpose

normalizeMatrix m = map (zipWith subtract columnMeans) m
    where
        columnMeans = getColumnMeans m
```

`mean` does exactly what its name suggests and `getColumnMeans` is the function that you seem to have implemented yourself.

`normalizeMatrix` is the function that you are looking for. It takes in a matrix, computes its column means and then subtracts it from each of its rows via `map`.

`subtract` function is basically `(-)` but with its arguments flipped. I use it whenever I wanna map something like `subtract 5` and it reads like regular English. So, `subtract 5 10` would return `5`. Here, `zipWith subtract columnMeans` does it on an entry-by-entry basis for a row. `map` does this for all rows. Hope this is useful.

Comment: This answer will probably be more useful with a quick description of what is going on and perhaps how it works.

Comment: Sure :) Thanks for the feedback.